# Determining Volume of an Irregularly Shaped Triangular Prism

Tags: plotting

I need help using Mathematica to determine the volume of an irregularly shaped triangular prism. I have very little experience with Mathematica but thought this task could easily be performed using the program.

The shape generated should look like:

```
Graphics3D[Prism[{{3.767, 4.523, 1}, {0, 0, 0}, {7.948, -2.451, 0}, {3.699, 8.156, 1}, {1.146, 10.24, 0}, {4.837, 10.24, 0}}]]
```

I've tried using the `Volume[]` function but with no luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: probably a version/os related issue. `Volume[prism]` works in version 12.1, does not in version 11.3.

Answer (score 1):

Using `Volume` should work:

```
Volume[
  Prism[{
    {3.767, 4.523, 1}, 
    {0, 0, 0}, 
    {7.948, -2.451, 0}, 
    {3.699, 8.156, 1}, 
    {1.146, 10.24, 0}, 
    {4.837, 10.24, 0}
  }]
]
```

> 24.0747

So the volume is 24.0747 cubic units.